# Unable to load html pages through controller responces in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring boot and I have learned that I can load HTML pages through Controller classes with the help of Thymeleaf dependency. and it did really work initially but it isn't now. Here's is my Controller class

```
package com.example.demo2;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller2 {
    @GetMapping("/test2")
    public String sdf() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and here is my pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.5.RELEASE
 

com.example
demo2
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo2
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here is my project structure

[image]

Comment: hey can you move index.html file under the templates folder

Comment: @IsaToltar Yes This works! could you please explain why ?

Comment: static folder is for your css,image and js files, you need the put your view files into the templates folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@RestController` annotation does set different defaults to be used for REST Apis (like content types and so on). Try using `@Controller` for the class and `@RequestMapping` for the method.

Comment: NO luck! it throws an exception : org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException rror resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: Ah I see: please move the templates from /static into /templates - the static folder is only for images and css files that don't require some rendering